# Get the list of deployed Axis services from another Axis service

Tags: java, service, apache-axis, web

I have a question about how to obtain a list of deployed Axis services within another Axis service. here is the scenario. I am using Tomcat 7.0.14 and Axis 2-1.5.5 as the deployment environment. Suppose there are currently 5 Axis services deployed on Tomcat, namely A, B, C, D, E. And I want to write some code in service E so that it can obtain a service list containing all the deployed services, that is, A, B, C, D, E.

I have tried to use the ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem() method. But the method seemed to create a new Axis 2 isntance each time it is invoked. And since I used it in the constructor of a web service, it caused an infinite loop. (create Axis instance -> create service instance -> create Axis instance -> create service instance -> ...) So I would like to know is there a way to programmatically get a list of deployed services from another deployed service? (Just like the http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/listServices does). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the environment's `AxisConfiguration` object. It provides among other things a function called `getServices()` which returns a map of installed services.

If your service implements ServiceLifecycle, the `ServiceLifecycle.startup()` function is passed the AxisConfiguration object during service startup. Alternately, if your service class implements `Lifecycle`, then the `Lifecycle.init()` function is passed a `ServiceContext` object. You should be able to call `ServiceContext.getConfigurationContext().getAxisConfiguration()` to get the AxisConfiguration from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Kenster! I tried to implement the ServiceLifeCycle interface in my web service, but the startup() method doesn't get invoked during deployment. Any idea on how to let Axis engine call this method? By the way, I write my web service as POJO service. Maybe that's a problem? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I managed to get it work by implementing the Lifecycle interface. It now works correctly. Thanks! For those who are interested, here is an article discussing the difference between ServiceLifeCycle and Lifecycle. [link](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/11/axis2-services-lifecycle-vs.html)

Comment: That article doesn't spell it out as well as it could. To use the ServiceLifecycle feature, you have to add a `class="my.service.lifecycle.class"` attribute to the `service` element within your services.xml file. Once you've done that, `startup()` will be called when Axis2 first loads your service, and `shutdown()` will be called when Axis2 shuts down.